# Quick Replies not appearing in Facebook Messenger from Dialogflow Webhook Response

Tags: json, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot

I am trying to make a few QR buttons appear in my FBM bot app. Everything is working fine, webhook returns text messages to FBM no issue and they are rendered.

However, when I paste in the JSON for the QR buttons, they does not appear in FBM. No errors are recorded.

Oddly if I try some sample JSON for a card it all works !!

Here is the QR JSON snippet I am using. I generated from the dialogflow app.

```json
"fulfillmentMessages": [
  {
    "quickReplies": {
      "title": "Alternative Names",
      "quickReplies": [
        "Maroon",
        "Rouge",
        "Rot",
        "Reed",
        "Fushcia",
        "Cyan"
      ]
    },
    "platform": "FACEBOOK"
  } 
]
```

Here is the code snippet that I used for the card - this works :

```json
"fulfillmentMessages": [
  {
    "text": {
      "text": [
        fulfilmsg
      ]
    }
  },
 {
    "text": {
      "text": [
        "Sorry. xxxxxxxxx"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "text": {
      "text": [
        "Just type xxxxxx again."
      ]
    }
},
  {
    "card": {
      "title": "Available Slots",
      "subtitle": "pick one of the slots...",
      "imageUri": "https://github.com/fluidicon.png",
      "buttons": [
        {
          "text": "Go to Google",
          "postback": "www.google.com"
        },
        {
          "text": "Go to Dialogflow",
          "postback": "www.dialogflow.com"
        },
        {
          "text": "Go to Slack",
          "postback": "www.slack.com"
        }
      ]
    },
    "platform": "FACEBOOK"
  }
]
```

Ideally this is what I am expecting to work but doesn't :

```json
"fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            fulfilmsg
          ]
        }
      },
     {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "Sorry. This slot xxxxxxx."
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "Just type xxxxxx."
          ]
        }
  },
  {
        "quickReplies": {
          "title": "Alternative Names",
          "quickReplies": [
            "Maroon",
            "Rouge",
            "Rot",
            "Reeed",
            "Fuscia",
            "Cyan"
          ]
        },
        "platform": "FACEBOOK"
  },
]
```

Thanks in advance for any consideration.

Comment: Did you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the payload you can try,

```
const payloadJson = {
  text: 'Quick replies!',
  quick_replies: [
    {
      content_type: 'text',
      title: 'How to book order',
      payload: 'How to book order'
    },
    {
      content_type: 'text',
      title: 'Shipping charges',
      payload: 'Shipping charges'
    },
    {
      content_type: 'text',
      title: 'Exchange policy',
      payload: 'Exchange policy'
    },
  ]
}
```

Then,

```
const { Payload } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment')

const payload = new Payload(agent.FACEBOOK, payloadJson, { sendAsMessage: true, rawPayload: false })
agent.add(payload)
```